# MySQL table get the wrong data after union

Tags: mysql, union

I tried to make view using union for 3 table, every table works succesfully with the right data. after i try union, the data on totalqtyspb is get the wrong data.

datatype is varchar.

here's my code

```
SELECT
  p.PONumber,
  p.POdate,
  p.customername,
  p.description,
  p.poqty,
  SUM(q.deliveryqty) AS TotalQtySpb,
  p.poqty-SUM(q.deliveryqty) AS OTSPO
FROM
  tb_po p
INNER JOIN
  tb_rls q ON p.PONumber = q.PONumber AND p.description = q.description
GROUP BY
  p.PONumber,
  p.PODate,
  p.customername,
  p.description,
  p.poqty
UNION
SELECT
  PONumber,
  PODate,
  CustomerName,
  Description,
  POQty,
  '0' AS TotalQtySpb,
  poqty AS OTSPO
FROM
  tb_po
WHERE
  poreleasedate = ''
UNION
SELECT
  PONumber,
  PODate,
  CustomerName,
  Description,
  POQty,
  '0' AS TotalQtySpb,
  poqty AS OTSPO
FROM
  tb_po
WHERE
  poreleasedate != '' AND OutboundInbound = ''
```

i cant explain why data on totalqtyspb get the wrong data, already trying change to int datatype still not works.

Comment: what data exactly do you _want_ to get and what exactly is being returned?

Comment: The `UNION` will operator will just take both data sets, append them and remove dupes. Whatever "wrong data" means, it must be present in the individual queries.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yep it take both data sets me forgot to change datatype because get distraction too much in warning at query editor at phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it because you are selecting `TotalQtySpb` once as an `integer`, and twice as a `varchar` , so try replacing in the third and second query this:

```
  '0' AS TotalQtySpb,
```

To this:

```
  0 AS TotalQtySpb,
```

Although you didn't say what is wrong, so its just a guess.

Comment: if i change that, query will be error, but i will try change data type with your explanation without changing the query

Comment: Why would there be an error? this column is `int` in his first position

Comment: oh god its works, error show up because i tried the query in sql editor on phpmyadmin, i just forgot it will work because the datatype is int, too much concentration in warning symbol on query editor, thx :)